# Unable to Login to docusign in salesforce

Tags: salesforce, docusignapi

Please help me to fix the above issue

I have installed the docusign in my SF instance an tried to login my docusign account to Salesforce , i'm getting this error.
Image below:
[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hf82e.png)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to mention the correct DocuSign Environment in SF (Demo environment is for sandbox accounts and Production is for Live paid accounts).

The error message is the image is clear enough: you should login to your DocuSign account, go to Preferences (user menu) and then open Permissions. Make sure to enable the missing permissions. Contact your DocuSign Admin in case you don't have the proper access rights.